# Проблема с margin при изменении свойства border

Tags: html, css

Почему при изменении свойства `border` меняются отступы снизу и сверху? 
Есть код, приведенный ниже, он с `border` (в content_wrap ), и он отображается так

[image: 1]

Если убрать `border`, то будет выглядеть так:

[image: 2]

Листинг:

```css
#content_wrap{
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 980px;
  background-color:red;
}
#content{
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_wrap">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="top_menu">
            <li>СТУДЕНТАМ</li>
            <li>ОРДИНАТОРАМ</li>
            <li>Аспирантам</li>
            <li>Слушателям</li>
            <li>Контакты</li>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое явление называется **margin collapsing**. [Ссылка на документацию](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Горизонтальные `margin`'ы никогда не схлопываются, а вот с вертикальными все немного сложнее.

Проиллюстрирую немного на примерах, для этого будем использовать следующую базовую разметку:

```css
.b-wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.b-first {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: moccasin;
}
.b-second {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-wrapper">
  <div class="b-first">
  </div>
  <div class="b-second">
  </div>
</div>
```

Смежные (перекрывающиеся) `margin`'ы не схлопываются в следующих ситуациях:

1. если один из элементов корневой (`html`), пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27me7fqa/4/);
2. этот пункт связан с понятием *clearance*, он может возникнуть, когда блоку приходится "оплывать", тогда `margin`'ы не схлопываются (правдиво для случаев, когда у элементов нет `padding` или `border`). Можно поиграться на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27me7fqa/5/), если убрать `clear: both;`, то `margin`'ы схлопнуться. Вообще тема с плавающими (имеющими `float: *`) блоками заслуживают отдельного вопроса;
3. если один элемент вложен в другой и родительский имеет `border` или `padding`, тогда на вложенном элементе `margin` не схлопнется [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27me7fqa/9/).

Теперь можно сказать и о случаях, когда они все таки схлопываются:

1. если элементы находятся друг за другом в одном *block formatting context* (его создают внутри себя все элементы с `float`, абсолютным позиционированием, элементы, которые ведут себя, как блочные (`inline-block`, `table-cell`, `table-caption`), но не имеют `display: block` , и соответственно элементы с `display: block`) и `margin` положительный у обоих, то результатом будет больший [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27me7fqa/6/), а если какой-либо `margin` отрицателен, тогда результирующим значением `margin`'а будет их сумма, причем, если сумма получится отрицательной, то элементы наложатся друг на друга [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27me7fqa/7/);
2. если один элемент вложен в другой и родительский не имеет `border` или `padding`, или *clearence*, тогда вложенный элемент не будет отступать от родительского, а их `margin`'ы схлопнуться и у родительского будет больший из них, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27me7fqa/8/);
3. если блок не формирует *block formatting context* , а потомки имеют подсчитанную `min-height: 0`, `height: auto` или подсчитанную `height: 0`, то его верхний и нижний `margin` будет схлопываться [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27me7fqa/11/).

Comment: Всё четко, спасибо Rolandius . Я понял, что мой случай подходит под пункт 2 в списке, когда схлопываются. Третий пункт не особо понял ))

Comment: Я так понял, чтобы в моём случае Margin не схлопывался, оптимальным решением будет использовать border 1px цвета фона или padding 1px

Comment: @ilya-direct, в Вашем случае, я бы просто сделал у внешнего контейнера `padding`, а у внутреннего `margin` бы убрал.

Answer (score 0):

`border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);` - это бордюр белого цвета.
Он, как суслик... "Видишь суслика? - Нет. - А он есть!" - (c) ДМБ

Замените на `rgba(0,0,0,1)` и Вы его увидите.

Отступ пропадает потому без бордюра нет точки отсчета для `margin`.
Попробуйте заменить все `margin` на `padding: 10px;`

Comment: Вы немного неправы. Отступ пропадает не из-за этого, а по причине *margin collapsing*